# What happens when an audio JFET amplifier receives signals from two microphones?

Tags: amplifier, sound, jfet

I have seen [this](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCBsB0BMCsBTAtADnABgJzUpAzPmPKgCyxkmQgDsWI8Ip%20DKYYAUAErg3VbVUGEAJDCIYDFJAthc6PG69q%20WMKEy1Y8JmmztGBRwDGykdQT9q8qbYjJDzGmFSQsGMFjoD8pa9ClOUzA%20TWFLMIMA2w8QB2hmPCpUGlRYF09SMWjOEKyI0VgaWHBIcV15Ith8GNrbLK5EAGcASyaAFwBDADtjRA48kAjVcPgVMh1JaUNIF3RG1o6evo4AcyGxmQmI5hK5NY3qMDLD8Cw9sQ4AdyHi8AoZeBKwB4xr25L8J8fP77eAJx%2093QfiyL3Q4lqHEBX1%20JVBQMhMXeCNhTEg%20U2bxuCPB6Mx1hRGNOpEKWI4ACsmGTqGNRioSsgsoZAgh3nShqRhBzPHt2ScqgwTiNLqYeecoFyzhcwCgaCBUAlCLBYG4wPgMaqICyPNCheIJTzXkwaG8eEb0BziXImJCDNlFDcOSLILAsiKAfrIhyuTapiYoG7Iq6sr6ojFSPKZpA6IQSKR4J40m5soEDj7pD7SBDLusQ7bhPnSNmDBwAB5QeAsTz0NzoNTwzkgABuAHsAK7tcvgRhV0rc6j5LIAWRaxn%20rYADgALVvdRAAHSanArxCGGmO4VQLCHIFH46ns-nS9geoxBpK585ftsByvbsLUooOberfAlpe2i5WHoklTGCIBBtGedB8A4IA) JFET amplifier circuit in my notebook.

It is very possible that it isn't a practical amplifier and that they just tried to teach me about JFET applications, but I have two questions about it:

1. As it seems, the signals from the two microphones will superimpose each other in the gate. Is that a trivial thing to do? Will I be able to hear both microphones assuming that a speaker is connected to the output?
2. The output signal isn't linear, mostly because the JFET transistor is used here. Is it accepted to build such amplifiers? or will the quality of the sound decrease dramatically in practicality?

Comment: Can you post the schematic in your question so we don't have to follow a link to understand your question and the question still makes sense when the link dies? Make it easy for your readers! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. If you connect two signal sources together like this (with resistors in series), the signals will get added. This is commonly done when you want to mix together two separate audio signals. You will just hear both at the same time with no ill effects.
2. The signal looks distorted and it will sound just as distorted. It'll sound similar to a cheap speaker that's turned up way too much (so it starts clipping / distorting the signal).

In reality, you'd incorporate some kind of negative feedback loop into the circuit to linearize it and eliminate the distortion. The circuit's component values also don't seem to be chosen correctly (the output coupling capacitor is way too small, for example).

[Here's the same circuit but with its component values and input voltage fixed.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCBsB0BMCsBTAtADnABgJzUpAzPmPKgCyxkmQgDsWI8Ip%20DKYYAUAErg3VbVUGEAJDCIYDFLHQIw%20dHjde1fLGFCQa%20eEzSMssUYNKAxipHUE-agqn2IyA1NSRS8eAPKwwsSFlhYGSlOczA%20LXUQa0idZ3sMR3jXDFhSYho%20LF8sdHjOcNJo%20BtomiCwSHE9BVhy-ATG%20yKuRABnAEs2gBcAQwA7U0QOQuLVKJj8Ml1JfUV-FlbOnoGhjgBzMa1pmOYg%20Q2tyuEYsADjDgB3MoqKLXhbvKub%206D8B9exDgAnT990UhucB3cSNH6fd5BQFFSFGWb2Z7Qz5ImIYRFA-5MIGo9FFXaiHEAKyYBJKDCqWzUIGQRXyCGeJRO5XJwm0Xx4jOB6E5QJ0pFBxhkSmunLZkDSsS%20v1FUU5-J0sw45nFMKiKqY%20mCzRoMjwNHIGAauQw%20vwNEY%20UOcukctIeS%20m3V8qgEtIdouAA9wIx4CxwjqyXiigBZDqmb4AewADgALCP9RAAHTanC9xGimn9GZYQZAofD0bjCeTsCVLOiGHQbhOleM0EaEHw0DUzEgJSwHnKYFI9Et12rFfQNAweNraN%20w9HQ5HGft8LRm0ns9oM8Iti%20IopaWEnPUT2lW9rnMxoKkHAj0WovI1WF7zd8Fvr9iwfBKCCMQT8Wg4QA)

Comment: There may be ill effects to connecting the signal sources together like that. Many signal sources don't like it when you feed current back into them, and connecting the two microphones together like that lets that happen. This is why your common op amp adder circuit has an op amp involved.

Comment: @Hearth The signal sources aren't connected directly, there are 1µF blocking capacitors and 100k resistors in series. Driving 100k is not a problem at all for an audio signal source even if that 100k resistor doesn't return directly to ground. Adding audio signals like this is perfectly fine.

Comment: I managed to completely miss the capacitors; I thought it was just resistors, an arrangement which works, but which I don't like to use on principle. Though driving 100k might be difficult for a bare condenser microphone, for instance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of your replies. What about the fact that it is a JFET? I think that it is considered not to be good while transferring linear signals. (Unless I am mistaken and it is only true for source follower,

Comment: JFETs are fine for analog circuits and in fact almost your only option when you need very low input currents. You just have to use them properly. If you need a buffer, a BJT is almost always a better option than a JFET, but JFETs are great for differential amplifiers, for example.

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd JFETs are *way* better for linear amplification than MOSFETs, at least. And when you're amplifying a condenser microphone with its minuscule drive current, you can't use low-input-impedance BJTs. No one makes IGBTs intended for linear applications, either.

Answer (score 2):

JFET’s are used inside all electret mic’s because they can buffer with gain and low noise. The gain is controlled by an external drain R pullup to 3.3, 5 or 12V, which is chosen to centre the idle voltage for large swings based on the Idss current.

Mixing 2 signals from the same mic types is commonly done for redundancy for podium mics.

Electret mics have a wide span and if the rear is blocked will pickup very far away (too distracting) but are made with an open rear for differential far field attenuation. (Out of phase) This is a delicate balance and hampered by a dust filter and often works poorly in cheap lapel mics. But if done right , avoids feedback near a speaker monitor.

Here with 2 variable levels in phase, nothing exciting happens.  But if one mic was inverted you could use dual magnetic mics as near-field mics and cancel out of phase.

To [demonstrate](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCBsB0BMCsBTAtADhLV9oE4DMYeALAOx4LwlhEgk4jwhF4MoCMbAUAEohsmQQOQagjDwfPmGkgWEedHg8%20A2bAii18yW2kQ5s6G3iE2OWDhyoiOAaXCLOAYxWDxCN4IV7pbEMjBoMEhgsmESEng8eGYcIkZA32dXLQx4QXJtRJ8-RMhSMEo8SGILfnIHJP4aDyFBWBJYPhCdPQdGiJBuRABnAEsegBcAQwA7J0ROarSM9RnZa1aZQI6SLt6BkfHJgHN5vEXa5ib5Tj3athaL8wkwTgB3DEa%20TFl4JrZXu8eGpui-95vE6cABOQJe6CI%20QhEl0PlB4P%20TGhSIgcL0D2RNCRUJq6XAmNxMKJtW%20WPmNnq%20LuACsmO58ekILUKsgaNlPkpHkyMEQIDyzMDuVdnjzMgSXAKbvk0Tc0Sg1jBIrZLqhImwiJgrJUwFwwVKmgKvkwqMojegedDtHypLcHFyGC1xZBYNi5nd9U65jy%20do4ckXW6IIGmMsddJ7IFIKgYzY8Gw8HZYycgrqzo6IL6M0wiOhTnsQ1nC7nbpwAB5QKJ8SxQbXqJo1GgANwA9gBXQblviMKuXfmCRsgACyfScIJbAAcABYt0aIAA6PS4FeMGE0fbXLEHI7Hk5nc8XsARMurTRPrr9GILNovUBvMdLfJYIc0kQ%20RHZGBwAH14J9v2A37MC6AGprmqCYJyoE%20LYkDpAgAHfrASE-ngnAtnwFqfBIfI1ro4ZgLB8EJBgmGyJwBySDQfjFBAAAKU7DD0C49AA8gAZuxzGdkAA) this I made slider for V2 phase centered at 180 deg. shift from V1 with 0 to 360 full slide. So you can see the minor effect of cancellation with different pot gains.

This technique is also how they null voice from recordings for Karaoke.

You can measure the linearity by changing the low levels and computing then % difference in Vp- and Vp+ You can easily get 1% THD at 100mV out and useful to 1Vpp output. But beyond 10% imbalanced peaks or THD it’s pretty crappy.

So electret mics still need another amp to get to 1V line voltage.